# How to create a table based on a condition automatically?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a table with 7 columns. I need that when the value of one of the columns is changed to "Ok", the content of that line is copied to another worksheet, but only the content of columns 1, 2 and 4. and that it be done automatically.
I made a code but it is only returning the last record.
In this table I have at least 3 rows that satisfy the condition.
What am I doing wrong?

```
var plan = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const PlanVistoria = plan.getSheetByName("Vistoria");
const PlanObras = plan.getSheetByName("ListaObras");
const Ultm_LinhaObras = PlanObras.getLastRow();
const Utlm_LinhaVistoria = PlanVistoria.getLastRow()+1;
var PlanPesquisa = PlanObras.getRange("B2:H"+Ultm_LinhaObras).getValues();


function ClassificarEapagarLinha() {

    PlanObras.getRange("A2:H").sort({column:2, ascending: true});

}


function PesquisarRecortarValoresColunaStatus() {  

    for(var linha = 0 ; linha<PlanPesquisa.length; linha++){
      if(PlanPesquisa[linha][6] == "OBRA CONCLUÍDA"){
        var sala = PlanPesquisa[linha];
        var dados_sala = [sala[0],sala[1],sala[4]];

       PlanVistoria.getRange("A"+Utlm_LinhaVistoria+":A"+Utlm_LinhaVistoria).setValue(sala[0])
       PlanVistoria.getRange("B"+Utlm_LinhaVistoria+":B"+Utlm_LinhaVistoria).setValue(sala[1])
       PlanVistoria.getRange("C"+Utlm_LinhaVistoria+":C"+Utlm_LinhaVistoria).setValue(sala[2])
       PlanVistoria.getRange("D"+Utlm_LinhaVistoria+":D"+Utlm_LinhaVistoria).setValue(sala[4])

      }
    }

}
```

I did a "for" but it's only returning the last record.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample sheet with dummy data including your desired output?Remove sensitive information

Answer (score 0):

It's not the most efficient way, but you can insert this variable *inside the loop* so it recalculates the last row each time

`const Utlm_LinhaVistoria = PlanVistoria.getLastRow()+1`

Other way, more efficient, would be to create an array by pushing the values and then set values only once

Comment: I've done it this way. The problem is that it only shows the last data in the list and not all of them as expected.